# Can't access specific admin pages

Tags: 8

I have a Drupal 8 site set up in Docksal. It was version 8.6.15, and needed updates to core and several modules. Bear with me - I don't have complete notes, because I thought everything had worked. I'm more than happy to debug... I just don't know where/how/what to look for in this case.

I would just roll back to a backed up version of the site. But that is missing ( My own fault)

The first problem I encountered, was not being able to update with Drush anymore. So I used composer to to attempt updating, with "composer require drupal/core --update-with-all-dependencies" - this was my first time doing so.

It didn't work. I had to update composer in order to continue on. After using "composer prohibits Drupal/core:8.7.3," I got several results, so I went ahead and updated them. I would tell you all I uploaded, but that was yesterday and I did not save those notes. Sorry. I also did an update of composer itself, all the packages. that appeared out of date. There were a couple that would not update, rejected by constraints.

Updated composer, and Drupal is now 8.7.3. I also did a bunch of module updates on the site as well.

I have an issue where the admin area shows I'm still on Drupal 8.6.15, even though Composer shows the latest version. I assumed this was a separate issue, but maybe it's related. There is an issue with this site being set up with drupal/drupal and not drupal/core. Something to do with the composer json.

Everything seemed fine, but when I tried to navigate to some of the admin pages (Content, Configuration or People page), I get an error:

> **Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required** '/var/www/docroot/vendor/composer/../doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Reflection/ClassFinderInterface.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /var/www/docroot/vendor/symfony/class-loader/ApcClassLoader.php on
>   line 112

Not even sure what first steps might be on this. When I type composer outdated, I don't see anything called class-loader or classfinder

Looking at ApcClassLoader.php, I see 'require $file;' on line 112:

```
 public function loadClass($class)
    {
        if ($file = $this->findFile($class)) {
            require $file;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: By just stating facts you make your question too broad. Plus debugging always needs to be done by you, this can't be done from afar. Please update your question to provide a reproducible problem, telling us what you've tried yourself so far and what exactly you've done before your page went nuts. Many thanks :)

Comment: @leymannx I just tried to add more detail, but I really don't know what is needed. I'm more than happy to debug and report back. I just don't know where/how/what to look at in this case. And I can't recall ever step taken. If I could just go to a backup and start over, I would. but that file is missing/gone. Let me know if there's something specific I can provide, and I'll try to see if I can.

Comment: Much better now! Thank you. You may want to have a look at https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal. I remember vaguely that drupal/drupal doesn't work anymore since version 8.7. or so. And apart from that what you are doing is really dangerous. Updating a live site like that, untested (as in locally on your own computer), no backups, no version control, really... Don't do that anymore! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether or not this will actually fix your issue, but I'd try:

- update the drupal/core version to in composer.json to be ^8.7.0
- if you're using webflo/drupal-core-require-dev, update that to ^8.7.0 as per https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer
- run `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies`
- run your database updates, `drush updb` or site.com/update.php

If that still doesn't work, try:

- deleting your vendor directory, core directory, and composer.lock
- run `composer install`

Comment: on the second option, "composer install" doesn't install the core directory, it seems. Is there an extra step, or did something not do what it should've?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. It won't install without a composer.install file. I think you'll need to composer update or another composer require

Comment: got it...the first option didn't do anything. so I used composer update. Then did composer update drupal/core --with-dependancies, and got several errors for "egulias/email-validator". it seems to be a recurring problem for people. I tried updating the validator, but got same errors:     can only install one of egulias/email-validator[2.0.x-dev, 1.2.15]. and a couple regarding installation request satisfiable by each of the same versions. 2.0.x-dev and 1.2.15. I'm starting to think I'm forced to start over from an 5-month old version of the site. This one's buggered

Comment: uh... here's a strange one... On a whim, after having done the above... I restarted PHP, then I restarted the docksal project. I was suddenly able to access the pages I couldn't. Now I'm just getting an error when I try to export a tar file of the site: Fatal error: Class 'Archive_Tar' not found in /var/www/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Archiver/ArchiveTar.php on line 8