# Fatal error: Class 'Archive_Tar' not found in ArchiveTar.php on line 8

Tags: 8

Rather than re-explaining the whole process that got me here, I'm hoping I can just reference this question: [Can't access specific admin pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282762/cant-access-specific-admin-pages/282767?noredirect=1#comment351430_282767)

In that question, I was hitting errors while trying to update Drupal. I updated composer as well.

After clearing caches, restarting PHP and restarting my docksal project, the errors went away, and the admin seems usable except the specific thing I need

A backup tar was lost during all of that, so I'm trying to create a new back-up, so I'm back to safety. But, when I go to the export page, here: page */admin/config/development/configuration/full/export*, I click the export button, and it gives me a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Archive_Tar' not found in /var/www/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Archiver/ArchiveTar.php on line 8

When I look in the log, I see this message:

> The file */tmp/config.tar.gz* was not deleted because it does not exist.

This is Drupal 8.7.3 , if that helps.

I would just do `drush archive-backup`, if I could. But that option has ben removed.

Not sure if I gave enough info, above. Let me know.

Comment: Your installation is probably incomplete. The `pear/archive_tar` package is a dependency of Drupal and it is missing or your composer autoloader is not returning classes.

Comment: I just tried installing pear/archive_tar with composer, and I got the same errors I keep getting for everything - "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." And it always references egulias/email-validator . It did show "Using version ^1.4 for pear/archive_tar" ... so, I'm assuming my issue is the non-returning classes? Any thoughts on how to repair that?

Comment: If composer is failing, then the vendor, core and other drupal-TYPE directories won't be updated. That's probably why you think you're updated, but may not actually be.